# My Stack Overflow profile's "About Me" section changed

Tags: support, security

This was a weird message in my Stack Overflow "About me" section and I didn't put it in the section:

> *Flowers for* you stackoverflow ..... you don't know who i am ...... i am your *flowering* god !!!! *flowers for* you all *nice ladies* on Stack Overflow

(some offending language replaced with random italicized phrases)

Why and how did this happened?

Can I see my login history? (I changed it now)

Comment: If there's an edit history for user profiles, I'm not aware of it.  Which method of "login" do you use?

Comment: i use fb Login..

Comment: I think your selection of the [meta-tag:bug] is a poor choice.  I would suggest retagging as [meta-tag:support] and ask the question.... "why did my about me change

Comment: Your account may have been compromised. Do you have signs of suspicious activity on other (non-SE) accounts of yours?

Comment: Your profile says you are a student. My guess is that you left yourself logged in at a public terminal.

Comment: Or maybe it's time to think about a new password...

Comment: I can (and will) clear all your sessions just in case you've left yourself logged in elsewhere. This will mean you'll have to log in again even on the computer you're using right now.

Comment: Is there any option in StackOverFlow to logOut from all current devices...I cann't find it.This is important because i used this account in my resume and i don't want such stuff happen again.

Comment: Yes. Click logout and there is a checkbox for exactly that.

Comment: The new logout with checkbox thingy is broken. It's saying that it will also (very helpfully) log me out from askubuntu.com and serverfault.com when I don't even have an account for it.

Comment: @mmking: I'm pretty sure that's just a list of all the different domain names that SE uses. You don't have an account on mathoverflow.net or stackapps.com, either, but I assume you see those in the list too, right?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, I do, but it shouldn't be telling me that it will log me out of mathoverflow.net if I don't have an account.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To put it frankly, the edit came from your account on an existing login session from a couple days before. Past that, there's really not anything else we'd be able to tell you about what happened here on Stack Overflow that you don't already know happened.

Keep in mind that since you are accessing the site using Facebook credentials, you need to make sure your Facebook account is secure as well. If you left yourself logged into Facebook somewhere or your Facebook account got compromised, another user could easily access your Stack Overflow account by using your Facebook session. All they'd have to do is log in and select Facebook and your already-logged-in Facebook account can quickly get them into your Stack Overflow account.